# Failed to build a Cordova Android project: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a Cordova project and when I try to build it for the Android platform, I get the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7ReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/xyz/projects/test-app/platforms/android/src/main/libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.263 secs (node:62024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error:
>   /Users/xyz/projects/test-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override
>   a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note:
>   /Users/xyz/projects/test-app/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/AssetFilesystem.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7ReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/xyz/projects/test-app/platforms/android/src/main/libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar'.

I am not an Android developer so I feel a bit lost.
Looks like something is messed up with the Android build tools setup.
Any ideas how to go about solving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is a problem with the appsflyer plugin.
When I removed it, the app got compiled successfully.